# Enable DirectorySlash without showing query

Tags: apache, .htaccess

If I have this code in my .htaccess in the root of my site:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/bar/
RewriteRule ^foo/bar(.*)$ http://example.org/foo/?file=$1 [P,QSA]
```

And have this file structure:

```
foo
 +-- index.php
 +-- bar
      +-- qaz
           +-- file.txt
```

And I request the page `http://example.org/foo/bar/qaz/` it will redirect on the server to `http://example.org/foo/?file=/qaz/`.
However if I request the page `http://example.org/foo/bar/qaz` it will redirect to `http://example.org/foo/?file=/qaz`, however it will display `http://example.org/foo/bar/qaz/?file=/qaz` in the browser.

How do I enable the DirectorySlash, but still hide the query from the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DirectorySlash only does this if the directory '/foo/bar/qaz' exists.

DirectorySlash doesn't respect rewriteBase. You could disable it and do it yourself with this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R,L]
```